# Teste de API passando token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testes, oauth2, token

Bom dia,

Estou fazendo Teste de Api, como segue o exemplo:

```
@Test
public void shouldStatus200_FindAll() {
    RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();

    given().basePath("/receitas")
           .port(port)
           .accept(ContentType.JSON)
    .when().get()
    .then().statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
}
```

Como no sistema tem implementado Token, o teste apresenta um erro de autenticação, segue o erro:

```
{
"error": "unauthorized",
"error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

Como faço para passar autenticação no teste, para verificar corretamente?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, segue em exemplo:

```
@Test
public void shouldStatus200_FindAll() {
    RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();

    given().auth().oauth2("String token")
           .basePath("/receitas")
           .port(port)
           .accept(ContentType.JSON)
    .when().get()
    .then().statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
}
```